# Return QuerySet with extra pagination fields

Tags: python, django

My get_queryset return this. Also, this fields with ID's are foreign keys serialized.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1389,
        "nome": "Curso teste",
        "nivel": {
            "id": 5,
            "nome": "Ensino Fundamental II"
        },
        "modalidade": {
            "id": 4,
            "nome": "Presencial"
        },
        "periodo": {
            "id": 5,
            "nome": "Matutino"
        },
        "ano": {
            "id": 21,
            "nome": "12º Semestre"
        },
        "instituicao": {
            "id": 35,
            "nome": "Fncit-escola"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to add to each object an extra pagination object, and it would be like this object below.

But get_queryset do not accept this kind of object, and if I use just get, and serialize the queryset, it will not come with the ForeignKeys serialized, it will return only the id's of the Foreign keys.

Anyone knows how do I return an object like this?

```
   [
    "bolsas":{
        "id": 1389,
        "nome": "Curso teste",
        "nivel": {
            "id": 5,
            "nome": "Ensino Fundamental II"
        },
        "modalidade": {
            "id": 4,
            "nome": "Presencial"
        },
        "periodo": {
            "id": 5,
            "nome": "Matutino"
        },
        "ano": {
            "id": 21,
            "nome": "12º Semestre"
        },
        "instituicao": {
            "id": 35,
            "nome": "Fncit-escola"
        }
    },
    "pagination": {
       "elements": 1
     }
]
```

I want to return this object:

```
        retorno = {
        'bolsas': bolsas,
        'paginacao':{
           'ultimo': True if int(totalElementos) - int(limite) == 1 else False,
           'primeiro': True if pagina == 0 and int(limite) == 1 else False,
           'totalPaginas': totalPaginas,
           'totalElementos': totalElementos,
           'elementos': elementos,
           'offset': pagina

        } 
    }
```

Where bolsas is the queryset

Comment: Did you write any pagination code?

Answer (score 0):

On pure Django you have the [Paginator class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/):

```py
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
>>> p = Paginator(objects, 2)

>>> p.count
4
>>> p.num_pages
2
>>> type(p.page_range)
<class 'range_iterator'>
>>> p.page_range
range(1, 3)
```

If you're using [django-rest-framework (DRF)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/), you have a few more options and more flexibility to customize your paginator. By `limit` and `offset`, with `next`, `cursor` pagination or some custom paginator.

---

Having said that, from your code examples, maybe it seems what you're looking for is a Serializer and not a Paginator? You could also leverage DRF for that or use either a simple object constructor or a Manager.

An example:

```py
payload = {
    'bolsas': bolsas_queryset.values()
    'other_properties': {
        'some_other_object': None
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, I gave a pagination example, but it could be anything. I just want to return the queryset plus some extra information, but using get_queryset I can only return the queryset.

Comment: Call .values or .values_list on the queryset and build the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

I serialized the queryset like this:

bolsas_serialized = BolsaSerializer(bolsas, many=True).data

and then could use like this

```
        retorno = {
        'bolsas': bolsas_serialized,
        'paginacao':{
           'ultimo': True if int(totalElementos) - int(limite) == 1 else False,
           'primeiro': True if pagina == 0 and int(limite) == 1 else False,
           'totalPaginas': totalPaginas,
           'totalElementos': totalElementos,
           'elementos': elementos,
           'offset': pagina

        } 
    }


return Response(retorno)
```